# Releated to xml spring configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring

spring is not responding proper xml response
[Here I am getting this type of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5UNR.png)
But before passing this response to spring controller I am getting the proper value of betsoftFinalResponse

[here in debug mode I am able to get betsofteFinalResponse properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OajJg.png)

But while it is sending response to the client It is not giving proper output

Here is my component class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BetSoftFinalResponse{

    @XmlElement(name = "REQUEST", required = true)
    private BetSoftRequest betSoftRequest;

    @XmlElement(name = "TIME", required = true)
    private String time;

    @XmlElement(name = "RESPONSE", required = true)
    private BetSoftResponse betSoftResponse;
//getters and setters
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BetSoftResponse {

}
```

---

```
public class BetSoftAuthenticationResponse extends BetSoftResponse{

    @XmlElement(name = "RESULT", required = true)
    private String  Result;

    @XmlElement(name = "USERID", required = true)
    private String  userId;

    @XmlElement(name = "USERNAME", required = false)
    private String  usernName;

    @XmlElement(name = "FIRSTNAME", required = false)
    private String  firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "LASTNAME", required = false)
    private String  lastName;

    @XmlElement(name = "EMAIL", required = false)
    private String  email;

    @XmlElement(name = "BALANCE", required = true)
    private String  balance;

    @XmlElement(name = "CURRENCY", required = true)
    private String  currency;

//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Serializable interface also but it was showing the same output.I got the solution I have added @XmlSeeAlso(value="{}") annotation to my superclass BetSoftResponse and I am able to get proper output.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to implements Serializable interface for you response classes.

Comment: Thanku,I tried with Serializable interface also but it was showing the same output.I got the solution I have added @XmlSeeAlso(value="{<subclass>}") annotation to my superclass  BetSoftResponse  and I am able to get proper output.